# jQuery Mobile Slider Step Attribute Not Working

Tags: jquery-mobile

i am using Jquery mobile slider.I want make the slider in steps.
so i have tried with this.

```
<div data-role="page">
<div data-role="content">
    <label for="slider" class="ui-hidden-accessible">Input slider:</label>
    <input type="range" name="slider"   id="slider_0" value="25" min="0" max="100" step="25" />
</div>
```

the slider is sliding well but it is not moving in the steps.

eg:  100/25 =4

so it should point only at 25,50,75,100 but its sliding every where.

I have seen an live example at this place. its working fine here but why its not working for me.

http://code.jquery.com/mobile/latest/demos/docs/forms/slider/index.html

here is my jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/chakrirajni/pfNDB/

Thanks,

Comment: Which aspect isn't working? Not displaying? Not moving? could you elaborate?

Comment: Interesting, the slider step option is here http://code.jquery.com/mobile/latest/demos/docs/forms/slider/ but not here http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0/docs/forms/slider/index.html also http://code.jquery.com/mobile is using jQuery 1.7.1 which jQm only supports 1.6.4 and maybe I'm missing it but I don't see the jQM js lib in the header as well

Comment: Chatting with @jquerymobile on twitter they said this should be working with release 1.0.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Bug has been Fixed in Latest version JQuery Mobile Libraries mentioned below

1)stable version - 1.0.1 http://jquerymobile.com/blog/2012/01/26/jquery-mobile-1-0-1-released/

2)Unstable build - 1.1.0 RC1 http://jquerymobile.com/blog/2012/02/28/announcing-jquery-mobile-1-1-0-rc1/

Answer (score 0):

Ya got it.

I have used these likns.

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.0-rc.1/jquery.mobile-1.1.0-rc.1.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.0-rc.1/jquery.mobile-1.1.0-rc.1.min.js"> </script>
```

its working fine.

but i dont want to see the textbox beside the slider. how can i do that in this version in 
my code looks like this.

```
         <label for="slider" class="ui-hidden-accessible">
                            Input slider:</label>
                        <input type="range" name="slider" id="slidstep" step="25"   value="0" min="1" max="100"/>
```

[image]

Thanks for ur help.